# IIFE functions being called before dom is ready angular

Tags: angular, angular6, iife

I am developing a  application using angular 6. i have a javascript framework file which contains some common event binding logic which are IIFE functions.

IIFE methods are getting called even before the DOM is loaded. As a result events are not getting binded.

How to load the js files after the DOM is loaded so that IIFE functions are called at later stage.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately-invoked function expressions provide a scope for variables like JavaScript modules do. Angular relies on modules, and you don't need both.

You should try to integrate the framework into your Angular application. Can you use Angular's [event binding](https://v6.angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding---event-) instead? If not try plugging the code into one of your root component's [lifecycle hooks](https://v6.angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#).

Alternatively you can plug it into the [load event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) of the document:

```
document.addEventListener("load", aFunction);
```